# Rails nested resources redirection after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good day all, I'm pulling my hair out on this one, I've seen similar posts but none of them get me in the direction I'm trying to go. 
That said, I've got a pretty complex app that's relying heavily on nested resources and name-spacing, when I save a record it saves perfectly
and redirects correctly. When I update that same record the URL changes but not as I would expect. I understand the flow from edit to update and 
the set_input call pulling the params[:id], what I don't understand is why the URL is changing the parents resource to reflect the record ID.

```
/servers/1/features/rsyslog_inputs/12/edit"
```

changes to the following after update

```
/servers/12/features/rsyslog_inputs/12/edit"
```

**LOGS**

```
Started GET "/servers/1/features/rsyslog_inputs/12/edit" for 127.0.0.1  at 2017-12-08 12:27:55 -0600
Processing by Features::RsyslogInputsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"server_id"=>"1", "id"=>"12"}
  RsyslogInput Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "rsyslog_inputs".* FROM "rsyslog_inputs" WHERE "rsyslog_inputs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering features/rsyslog_inputs/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.4ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered features/rsyslog_inputs/_form.html.erb (4.3ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered features/rsyslog_inputs/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms) [cache miss]
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_navbar_top.html.erb (0.9ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered layouts/_navbar_side.html.erb (0.5ms) [cache miss]
  Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 84.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Here the PATCH has modified the servers/:id to reflect the id of the rsyslog_inputs and not retained its "1" as shown above

```
Started PATCH "/servers/12/features/rsyslog_inputs/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-08 12:27:58 -0600
Processing by Features::RsyslogInputsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dFt61NcQWXoKpmScrkngT47ZxDdhzMUcCyJ5fZKrdbaOVqKfLXMVeBUj20zKKHQ8wGe4fi2QEw98cLviyO4wQw==", "rsyslog_input"=>{"inputs_interface"=>"eth04", "inputs_ip_address"=>"1.1.1.1", "inputs_input_type"=>"tcp", "inputs_port_number"=>"22", "inputs_input_name"=>"test02", "inputs_tls"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Save Input", "appliance_id"=>"12", "id"=>"12"}
  RsyslogInput Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "rsyslog_inputs".* FROM "rsyslog_inputs" WHERE "rsyslog_inputs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  Server Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "servers".* FROM "servers" WHERE   "servers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "rsyslog_inputs" SET "inputs_interface" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "rsyslog_inputs"."id" = $3  [["inputs_interface", "eth04"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-08 18:27:58.904817"], ["id", 12]]
 (0.8ms)  COMMIT

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/servers/12/features/rsyslog_inputs
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

**Controller**

```
class Features::RsyslogInputsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_input, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    # Let's search for all inputs associated with the corresponding appliance
    @inputs = RsyslogInput.where(server_id: params[:server_id])
  end

  def create
    @input = RsyslogInput.new(input_params)
    @input.build_server
    @input.server_id = params[:server_id]
    if @input.save
      flash[:notice] = "Input was successfully saved."
      redirect_to server_features_rsyslog_inputs_path
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @input.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Input was successfully destoryed."
      redirect_to server_features_rsyslog_inputs_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Unable to destroy #{@input.inputs_input_name}"
    end
  end

  def update

    if @input.update(input_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Input was successfully updated"
      redirect_to server_features_rsyslog_inputs_path 
    else
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def new
    @input = RsyslogInput.new
  end

  def edit; end

  def show ;end

  private

  def set_input
    @input = RsyslogInput.find(params[:id])
  end

  def input_params
    params.require(:rsyslog_input).permit(:inputs_interface,
                                  :inputs_input_type,
                                  :inputs_ip_address,
                                  :inputs_port_number,
                                  :inputs_input_name,
                                  :inputs_tls,
                                  :server_id)
  end


end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for ([:server, :features, @input]) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <br/>

    <div class="form-group  clients-form-container">
      <%= f.label :inputs_interface, 'Input interface:', class: 'col-3 col-form-label' %>
      <div class="col-3">
        <%= f.text_field :inputs_interface, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Interface: (e.g. eth0)' %>
      </div>
      <br/>

      <%= f.label :inputs_ip_address, 'Input IP Address:', class: 'col-3 col-form-label' %>
      <div class="col-3">
        <%= f.text_field :inputs_ip_address, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter IP Address:' %>
      </div>
      <br/>

      <%= f.label :inputs_input_type, 'Input type:', class: 'col-3 col-form-label' %>
      <div class="col-3">
        <%= f.text_field :inputs_input_type, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'TCP/UDP' %>
      </div>
      <br/>

      <%= f.label :inputs_port_number, 'Input port number:', class: 'col-3 col-form-label' %>
      <div class="col-3">
        <%= f.text_field :inputs_port_number, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Port:' %>
      </div>
      <br/>

      <%= f.label :inputs_input_name, 'Input Name:', class: 'col-3 col-form-label' %>
      <div class="col-3">
        <%= f.text_field :inputs_input_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Ruleset Name)' %>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <%= f.label :inputs_tls, 'Enable TLS:', class: 'col-1 col-form-label' %>
        <div class="col-3">
          <%= f.check_box :inputs_tls, class: 'form-control check-box-alignment' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <%= f.submit 'Save Input', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', :back, class: 'btn btn-secondary region-btn btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
<br/>
```

**Routes**

```
resources :servers do
    namespace :features do
      resources :rsyslog_inputs
      resources :rsyslog, only: :index
    end
  end

  server_features_rsyslog_inputs            GET     /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs(.:format)          features/rsyslog_inputs#index
                                            POST    /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs(.:format)          features/rsyslog_inputs#create
 new_server_features_rsyslog_input          GET     /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs/new(.:format)      features/rsyslog_inputs#new
edit_server_features_rsyslog_input          GET     /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs/:id/edit(.:format) features/rsyslog_inputs#edit
     server_features_rsyslog_input          GET     /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs/:id(.:format)      features/rsyslog_inputs#show
                                            PATCH   /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs/:id(.:format)      features/rsyslog_inputs#update
                                            PUT     /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs/:id(.:format)      features/rsyslog_inputs#update
                                            DELETE  /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs/:id(.:format)      features/rsyslog_inputs#destroy
     server_features_rsyslog_index          GET     /servers/:server_id/features/rsyslog_inputs(.:format)          features/rsyslog_inputs#index
```

Comment: I also noticed that when I view the page source during an edit I get the following:

`action="/server/12/features/rsyslog_inputs/12"`

Answer (score 0):

seeing your forms, controller and the requirement, i would advice that you use the route helpers and pass in the appropriate parameters there

like in your form explicitly set the form url to 
`server_features_rsyslog_input(server_id: params[:server_id], id: @input.id)`

and in your controller too pass in the parameters explicitly

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot and let you know how it shakes out!

Answer (score 0):

So this actually turned out to be a redirection issue in the update method. I wasn't specifying the server_id which wouldn't allow the redirection back to the index based on the server.